# Get Only Before 5 Minutes Inbox SMS

Tags: android, android-sms

I want to select only latest inbox SMS on button click. Here is my code.

```
btnGet = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGet);
        btnGet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    if (fetchInbox() != null) {
                        ArrayList sms1 = fetchInbox();
                        for (int i = 0; i < sms1.size(); i++) {
                            String st = sms1.get(i).toString();
                            String[] sArr = st.split("\\$");
                            mobile = sArr[0];
                            sms = sArr[1];
                            useGet(mobile, sms);
                        }
                    } else {
                        textView1.setText("no sms");
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    textView1.setText("Exception" + ex.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });
```

And here is my function to fetch SMS.

```
public ArrayList fetchInbox()
    {
        ArrayList sms = new ArrayList();
        Uri uriSms = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uriSms, new String[]{"_id", "address", "date", "body"},null,null,null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while  (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            String id = cursor.getString(0);
            String address = cursor.getString(1);
            String body = cursor.getString(3);
            sms.add(address + "$" + body + "$" + id);
        }
        return sms;
    }
```

I am able get all inbox SMS by this code, but I want to select only before 5 minutes inbox SMS. I am new with android apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query (Uri uri, 
                String[] projection, 
                String selection, 
                String[] selectionArgs, 
                String sortOrder)
```

> **selection** : A filter declaring which rows to return. Passing null will
>   return all rows for the given URI.

As you can see, you can specifies the criteria for selecting rows.

First get the current date time.

```
Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
long t = date.getTimeInMillis();
```

Then subtract 5 mins from current time.

```
static final long ONE_MINUTE_IN_MILLIS = 60000;
Date afterSubtractingFiveMins = new Date(t - (5 * ONE_MINUTE_IN_MILLIS));
```

Now create the filter and query the messages.

```
String filter = "date>=" + afterSubtractingFiveMins.getTime();

Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uriSms, new String[]{"_id", "address", "date", "body"},filter,null,null);
```

PS: I didn't check the code. You may have to optimize.

Comment: Pleasure to hear that.